# Prove that eigenvalue of matrix A is the same as the eigenvalue of $BAB^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

So let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A$ and let $B$  be invertible. How do I prove that $\lambda$ is also an eigenvalue for $BAB^{-1}$

Comment: Ask Google about *Similar Matrices*.

Comment: Try showing that both $A$ and $B$ have the same characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$$ \det( \lambda I -BAB^{-1})= \det(B( \lambda I -A)B^{-1}).$$

Comment: From here I get to $\det( \lambda I -BAB^{-1})= \det(( \lambda I -A)BB^{-1})=\det(\lambda I - A)$ so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By definition of $\lambda$, $\exists x\neq 0$ such that $Ax=\lambda x$

$BAB^{-1}(Bx)$

$=BAB^{-1}Bx$

$=BAIx$

$=BAx$

$=B \lambda x$

$=\lambda Bx$

$=\lambda (Bx)$

If $BAB^{-1}(Bx)=\lambda (Bx)$ then clearly $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $BAB^{-1}$ (with $Bx$ is an eigenvector; invertibility of $B$ ensures $Bx$ is not zero).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have
$$ AX = \lambda X.$$
We show that  $Y= BX$  is an eigenvector of $ BAB^{-1}$ associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda.$
$$ BAB^{-1}(BX) = BAX = B(\lambda. X)= \lambda BX.$$